# Frame failure sudden death?

Tags: road-bike, frames, crash

I had a serious accident, my fork suddenly snapped when riding.
I sent my bike for repair (to get a new fork installed) and the guys at the shop hammered the frame in place, as apparently the frame bent from the crash. 
Now after the very scary crash I had, I am wondering if I should even ride the bike in that condition? I know it is impossible to predict how much time will it take for it to fail, but other than checking very often if the area next to the bumps changes, what else can I do? I know that getting new pieces welded is not an option as it is hard to weld aluminum and it is probably less expensive or equally expensive just to get a new frame.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think this is answerable with the information you've given. And, really, just like a doctor needs to see the patient to give an actual diagnosis, I don't think that anyone can say "that bike is safe" without physically inspecting it.

Comment: I know, but I am just paranoid that I will crash again, any tips so that I can inspect it myself to see if I need a professional to look at it?

Comment: @David Richerby, in the case Al frame & bending it back in shape it's clear cut. There is no way one can safely do that.

Comment: @gschenk I did carefully say "I don't think anyone can say 'that bike is safe to ride'" rather than "I don't think anyone can say whether that bike is safe to ride."

Comment: Honestly, with a serious crash, you're unlikely to ever feel safe riding the same bike again. Just get a new bike.

Comment: You have two choices if you want to enjoy riding the bike without worry.  Replace the frame, or go to a different bike shop and get a second opinion (then replace the frame).

Comment: Would be good to know exactly what the hammering LBS did.   I cannot understand how a crash caused damage at the lower end of both seat stays.   I'm guessing two spokes were replaced or do the red ones mark the valve stem ?

Comment: @Criggie I am not entirely sure that the crash caused the bending, but let's say it did, when it happened the front wheel stopped working as soon as the fork failed and as I wasn't going perfectly straight the rear of the bike went over the side and hit the pavement deforming the frame. No they didn't replace any spokes.

Comment: If hitting the pavement on its side deformed the seat stays, then the bike could be made of cheese.  Even an aluminium bike should have survived that.   I'd absolutely replace the frame.  Check your insurance to see whether its worth making a claim.

Comment: Yes indeed very bad quality materials, I don't know if I am going to get parts from GW again

Answer (score 29):

If an aluminium frame has to be bent back into alignment, it's trashed. Aluminium cannot be deformed without causing weakness in the material.

If the bicycle repair shop literally hit the seat stays with a hammer near the dropouts to straighten the frame is probably weakened in those areas and is very likely unsafe. I personally would not ride that frame.

The bicycle repair shop should have told you the frame was un-repairable and not replaced the fork. Maybe they wanted to make some money of a repair job but I can't believe they passed up an opportunity to sell you a new bike.

Comment: Or maybe hammering a frame that wasn't bent in the first place seemed like a good way to generate a new bike sale.

Comment: Better not assume malicious intent when incompetence explains behaviour sufficiently.

Comment: As always, in case of doubt abstain. And I'd keep out of that 'shop'.

Comment: @gschenk Unfortunately life has taught me that if you assume the worst then you usually aren't far wrong :(

Answer (score 10):

For the long term, that repair should not be trusted and the point of weakened aluminum is correct.  However, if this is your only transportation and you can't get anything else *immediately*, I would say it can be ridden until an alternative is found.

The front fork is two pieces, and if either side fails (or the center), the front wheel comes off and that normally results in an immediate, and often pretty bad crash.

If one of those weakened points on the rear wheel breaks, there is still another connection holding the wheel on (4 posts, two on each side).  Depending on how it breaks, the wheel may twist, but it's probably not going to immediately fall off.  In other words you will have some warning and the ability to stop (still have your front braking power).

So, again, long term - get a new bike, or argue with the shop that "repaired" it, but if its essential, I would ride that bike in the short term.

Comment: Something is safe to ride or it's not.

Comment: @Mast Uh, why do you say so? In real world, it is just a risk of it breaking, and the longer you use the larger the risk becomes. No bike is 100% safe to ride.

Comment: To me, saying that the bike needs to be replaced "in the long term" suggests some time in the next few years. I'd be OK with an answer that gave a message of "You should replace it as soon as you can but you're probably OK to ride it until your next paycheck or something, if you have to; be aware that this carries risks", but you seem to be suggesting "Yeah, you should plan to replace that eventually" which seems way too slow, to me.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that long term.  "Until an alternative is found" was meant to mean you should be actively looking for a replacement because the "repair" shouldn't be trusted for long.

Comment: @DavidRicherby if it's merely _likely to break_ but not likely to cause a bad crash, then it's entirely a matter of taste how long you're willing to ride it. I would ride any bike until it's definitely trash or a significant risk of killing me.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Any time your bike breaks under you is a time when you might get your skull crushed by a passing truck.

Comment: @jpa Metal fatigue and failure curves are complicated things. This isn't simple wear. The metal has been worked, and likely work hardened. Massive structural changed have occurred, making the Aluminium that was originally there a completely different material than what it is now. It is likely to be highly brittle rather than plastic. It will fail in completely different failure modes from before. It is not even close to being safe. You might as well ride a glass bike.

Comment: @DavidRicherby well, of course the killing-risk regime shifts depending on whether you usually drive on flat dedicated cycle-tracks, mud trails, stairsets, or you're so daring to go on roads where cars – let alone trucks – can drive. Granted, many road bikers do just that, daily. I could now say that this is _every time_ a time when you might get your skull crushed by a passing truck (whose driver happens to have overlooked you on your pristine high-quality steel bike). But again, this risk is for the individual to judge.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm sorry but riding a bicycle on the road is not "so daring". It is a completely normal activity performed by tens or hundreds of millions of people every day.

Comment: @DavidRicherby probably even more people, worldwide-speaking, drive wreck bicycles that are about to fall apart through rural areas where there are barely any cars. Others like to push their downhill MTBs through as dangerous terrain as possible. The point is, stop making assumptions about who does what and wants what, just point out what's likely to happen with bike X in situation Y. This answer is exemplary.

Comment: @Aron This answer contains an analysis of the likely failure modes, which seems quite reasonable to me. But I was objecting to Mast's claim that safe vs. not safe is always a clear-cut yes or no, which it is not.

Comment: @leftaroundabout More than tens or hundreds of millions of people? I'd like to see any evidence at all for that claim. And downhill mountain-biking is just a blip on the radar; there are half a billion bicycles in China, the majority of which are in urban areas.

Answer (score 1):

Don't take it to a bike shop, take it to a *reputable* frame builder particularly one who works in aluminum.

He'll have the jigs and the experience to tell you what's wrong with the frame and if it's reparable. He may be able to remove the entire rear triangle and replace it for less than it would cost to get an equivalent new frame, or he may tell you that it's simply not worth it.

I once had a huge wreck on a steel frame which misaligned the whole bike. A builder was able to adjust everything back into alignment and told me that the little wrinkle in the down tube was something to keep an eye on, but *should* be OK for a while. I put many thousand more miles on that frame. Of course, that was steel and this is aluminum, so your mileage may vary, but a frame builder will be able to be the best judge.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specific aluminum alloy and level of heat treat (if any) it's impossible to estimate what portion of the design safety margin has been compromised.  Fortunately that's not important.  The real question is how long to you want to ride a bike that may come apart unexpectedly?  You're the only one able to make that evaluation.

Answer (score -2):

Bending aluminium does not cause sudden failure. Take a piece of aluminium and try it your self.  Like any metal, repeatedly bending aluminium will gradually make it weaker. (This is a common failure mechanism for *very old* steel bikes).  Unlike steel, aluminium has no "absolute minimum" value for softness (which enables you to specify intrinsically safe steel components). For this reason, aluminium parts have to be over-specified, because they always just get gradually softer and softer in use.

Bicycle frames (especially expensive bicycle frames) are designed to be as light as possible. For this reason they are *shaped* into the most efficient shape possible. If you dent a tube out of shape, it will not be as strong as it would be. If you dent a tube on *any* bicycle, it will materially weaken the tube. This is not because it is Aluminium or Steel: it is because it is a tube.  On a bicycle some tubes are critical (the front forks, the head piece), some tubes are not critical (the cross bars: you can just keep on riding with broken cross bars), but will critical in traffic or when making a sharp turn on a fast downhill. And some tubes barely matter at all (the rear wheel posts), as you know if you've ever had one fail at speed in traffic.

The pictures you've posted show damage that hardly matters at all, at a location that matters very little. The effect of softening is marginal (bicycle alloys are *selected* for handling 1000's of repeated stress cycles), and it's a location where the change in shape is less than critical. The bike shop (which doubtless see *lots* of damaged bikes discarded), didn't even think it was worth trying to sell you a new bike.

If you ride a frame long enough and hard enough, it will fail. This frame may fail at the rear wheel, or, the way you're riding it, you may do the front forks again first.

Comment: If you use any object "long enough and hard enough", it will fail -- that's just what "enough" means. The question is, pretty much, how long and how hard is "long enough and hard enough".

Comment: It is correct that "bending aluminum does not cause sudden failure". I don't see anywhere in this conversation that anyone asserts this as true.

Comment: @David Richerby If you haven't had bicycle frames fail from fatigue, you haven't ridden long enough and hard enough. Many people haven't ridden a frame that long and that hard, and damage of this sort won't change that.

Comment: @David D Since nobody has asserted sudden failure, we can agree that sudden death, as questioned in the original post, is not going to happen.